# Dokka - skip generating javadoc for default android packages

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, javadoc, kotlin-dokka

I am trying to use Dokka plugin to generate Javadoc for android Kotlin application. I added the plugin to my gradle:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:0.9.15"
```

Then I made a basic configuration following project instructions:

```
dokka {
    outputFormat = 'javadoc'
    outputDirectory = "$rootDir/docs"
    skipEmptyPackages = true
    noStdlibLink = true
}
```

I generate documentation using basic gradle command:

```
[user@linux AppDir]$ bash gradlew dokka
```

Output is fine, but it includes multiple directories from android or plugins I have added to my project, for example:

```
android.R
android.support
com.google
com.crashlytics
.
.
.
etc.
```

How do I skip these packages? Is there any way to generate dock only for my /app/scr/java folder, and files I created? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dokka version 0.9.16 will include a [bugfix to remove generated files from documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/224).

In version 0.9.15, the following commit seemed to address that "[Suppress output of android.R and other generated stuff in dokka-android](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/commit/1121071276ca2ce0afeabf4d3e540d4d8103f311)", but apparently after creating the `suppresedFiles` map with the needed information, it was not really used to filter `sourceSets`.

---

**UPDATE**: [Dokka 0.9.16 has been released](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/releases/tag/0.9.16) with the fix, among other improvements.

> [#224](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/224) Filtered out Android generated classes from docs

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example with **Dokka 0.9.16**:

```
task dokka(overwrite: true, type: org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaAndroidTask) {
    outputFormat = 'javadoc'
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/docs"

    // Do not create index pages for empty packages
    skipEmptyPackages = true

    //Do not output deprecated members. Applies globally, can be overridden by packageOptions
    skipDeprecated = false

    //No default documentation link to kotlin-stdlib
    noStdlibLink = false
}
```

If you use Android then the type is important: `org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaAndroidTask`

Not `DokkaTask` but **`DokkaAndroidTask`**.

Comment: You'll also need to use the `org.jetbrains.dokka-android` plugin from the `org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:0.9.16` repository! Took me a looong time to figure that out.